# Watching Future<T> objects for completion using ExecutorService

Tags: java, future, executorservice, callable

I have a program wherein I'm downloading files from S3 using a Callable object submitted to an ExecutorService. The files are large, and take several minutes to fully download. Does it make sense to create another Callable class that takes the future from the downloader and watches it for completion? My end goal is to add all complete downloads to a centrally located List within a cache.

For example:

```
public void add(final String s3urlToDownload){

    Future<S3Object> futureS3obj = cachedPoolExecutor.submit(new S3Downloader(s3urlToDownload));

    // Instead of calling futureS3obj.get() and waiting, submit the Future to the "Watcher" service.
    // Within FutureWatcher, the S3Object will be added to the List once the download is complete.
    cachedPoolExecutor.submit(new FutureWatcher(downloadedList, futureS3obj))

}
```

Comment: What's the advantage of an extra `Callable` if you've already got a `Future`?

Comment: @Kayaman, To my understanding, if I called the `Future`'s `get()` method, the `add` method would block. That's why I submit a new Callable `FutureWatcher`

Comment: So what does the `Callable` bring in play? Calling its `call()` method would block too, since it delegates to `get()`.

Comment: Is this accurate: there are N files to download. They should be downloaded in parallel and there needs to be a mechanism to know when all are ready? If so, there might be other ways to go about this (I might try an answer, if this is accurate).

Comment: @MichaelEaster, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some fake objects, used for illustration. "Downloads" are just random sleeps:

```
// for illustration only
class S3Object {
    String id;
}

// for illustration only
class S3Downloader {

    public S3Object download(String url) {
        int min = 2;
        int max = 5;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int random = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

        try { Thread.sleep(1000 * random); } catch (Exception ex) {}
        S3Object result = new S3Object();
        result.id = url;
        return result;
    }
}
```

We can define a task that downloads the file, updates a (thread-safe) list, and decrements a `CountDownLatch`:

```
class MyTask implements Runnable {
    private final List<S3Object> list;
    private final CountDownLatch latch;
    private final String url; 

    public MyTask(List<S3Object> list, CountDownLatch latch, String url) {
        this.list = list;
        this.latch = latch;
        this.url = url;
    }     

    public void run() {
        S3Downloader downloader = new S3Downloader();
        S3Object result = downloader.download(url);
        list.add(result);
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

An example Runner illustrates the "client". The `go` method is the driver, and uses the `add` method (which does not block):

```
public class Runner {
    private ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private int numUrls = 20;
    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(numUrls);
    private List<S3Object> results = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<S3Object>());

    public void add(String url) {
        pool.submit(new MyTask(results, latch, url));
    }

    public void go() throws Exception {

        for(int i = 0; i < numUrls; i++) {
            String url = "http://example" + i;
            add(url);
        }

        // wait for all downloads
        latch.await();

        for (S3Object result : results) {
            System.out.println("result id: " + result.id);
        }
    }
}
```

Production code must handle errors and possibly reorganize the client as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I should be able to refactor my code to include the above framework.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a 'watcher' which consumes resources, make the current download notify the master on completion.